# Trying to find all instances of a class where the ID is not stored as a field in another class

Tags: mongoid

```
class Address
    has_one :order
end

class Order
    index({address_id: 1, background: true})
    belongs_to :address
end
```

An Order will always have an address_id, but an Address can exist without being related to by an Order.  I am trying to find all Addresses for which there is no Order such that order.address_id == address.id.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the test below, the method addresses_without_an_order answers your question via Rails/Mongoid.
It is easy and straightforward but inefficient, which may or not be important to you.
For further enlightenment, we'll assume that you want something more efficient.
The 1-to-1 relation is implemented via the foreign-key reference address_id on the Order collection.
So a simple query on the Address collection can't answer your question.
MongoDB does not implement joins between two collections (joins are given up in favor of sharding).

To get the equivalent of join with better efficiency in MongoDB, embed the child in the parent.
The method addresses_without_a_contact shows how easy it to answer your question with embedding.
For a 1-to-1 relation, embedding is easy and obvious and has significantly higher performance than joining.
Hope that this answers your question.

app/models/address.rb

```
class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :order
  embeds_one :contact
end
```

app/models/order.rb

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  index({address_id: 1}, {background: true})
  belongs_to :address
end
```

app/models/contact.rb

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :address
end
```

test/unit/address_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class AddressTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Address.delete_all
    Order.delete_all
    puts
  end
  test "0. mongoid version" do
    puts "Mongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  def addresses_without_an_order
    Address.all.collect{|address| address.order == nil ? address : nil}.compact
  end
  def addresses_without_a_contact
    Address.where(:contact.exists => false).to_a
  end
  test "Address" do
    address = Address.create(street: "229 W 43rd Street, 5th FL", city: "New York", state: "NY", zip: "10036")
    assert_equal 1, Address.count
    puts "addresses_without_an_order: #{addresses_without_an_order.inspect}"
    puts "addresses_without_a_contact: #{addresses_without_a_contact.inspect}"
    address.order = Order.create(ASIN: "B00DUW4BMS", title: "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)", author: "Bjarne Stroustrup")
    address.contact = Contact.new(name: "Isabel")
    assert_equal 1, Order.count
    assert_equal [], addresses_without_an_order
    assert_equal [], addresses_without_a_contact
  end
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/2] AddressTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.5
Moped::VERSION:1.5.1
[2/2] AddressTest#test_Address
addresses_without_an_order: [#<Address _id: 528a5fa37f11ba7227000001, street: "229 W 43rd Street, 5th FL", city: "New York", state: "NY", zip: "10036">]
addresses_without_a_contact: [#<Address _id: 528a5fa37f11ba7227000001, street: "229 W 43rd Street, 5th FL", city: "New York", state: "NY", zip: "10036">]
Finished tests in 0.054955s, 36.3934 tests/s, 72.7868 assertions/s.
2 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```